# Cannot delete a directory with rm -rf: Cannot remove directory not empty

Tags: linux

I am trying to delete some files but I think they are corrupted. When I run the command:

```
rm prog/*
```

I get the errors:

```
rm: cannot remove 'prog/20230412_00_000_prog_regular_grid_classic.nc': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'prog/20230412_00_001_prog_regular_grid_classic.nc': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'prog/20230412_00_002_prog_regular_grid_classic.nc': No such file or directory
```

And if I try and delete the whole directory:

```
rm -rf prog/
```

I get the error

```
rm: cannot remove 'prog/': Directory not empty
```

I cant find an example online where `rm -rf dir/` doesnt allow you to delete a directory.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

A process had a handle on those files. I stopped the process and the files were removed.